# How to see a iso label on windows and linux

Tags: iso-image, label, kickstart

I want to see the iso label info of an iso, for using in the kickstart,

how to see the iso label in windows as well as in linux?

example: am trying to find a iso image label for CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso

use this label in the kickstart file in inst.stage2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, the [volume id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) can be viewed with `isoinfo` (and can be [changed](https://serverfault.com/a/361479) too):

```
$ isoinfo -d -i file.iso | grep Volume\ id
Volume id: Fedora-S-dvd-x86_64-28
```

Under Windows, the (abbreviated) label of a *mounted* image can be displayed with [diskpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart):

```
$ echo list volume > foo
$ diskpart /s foo | find "CD"
  Volume 0     D   Fedora-S-dv  CDFS   DVD-ROM     2769 MB  Healthy
```

Comment: In Linux, your suggestion worked better, In Windows, your suggestion didnt work easy! anyhow would try